# How to set contenttype policy label programmatically?

Tags: content-type

I have a custom contenttype created in VS. I would like to set a policy label on this contenttype. How can I do this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add contenttype label policies as follow:

```
public static void AddPolicyToContentType(SPSite site)
        {
            SPContentType ct = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId("0x0101000ACB09B019144AB4A7A9EDD1CCCC4ED3")];

            const string PolicyName = "DMS Version Policy";
            // Policy XML for enabling all out of the box auditing
            const string LabelCustomData = "<label><segment type=\"metadata\">_UIVersionString</segment></label>";

            Policy policy = Policy.GetPolicy(ct);
            if (policy == null)
            {
                // Create new custom policy
                Policy.CreatePolicy(ct, null);
                // Retrieve newly created policy
                policy = Policy.GetPolicy(ct);

                if (policy == null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("policy");
                }

                // Update policy information
                policy.Statement = PolicyName;
                policy.Name = PolicyName;
                policy.Description = PolicyName;
            }

            if (policy != null)
            {
                // The PolicyId property provides the policyFeatureId parameter for the PolicyItemCollection indexer
                PolicyItem auditItem = policy.Items[PolicyLabel.PolicyId];
                if (auditItem == null)
                {
                    // Update policy with custom audit requirements
                    policy.Items.Add(PolicyLabel.PolicyId, LabelCustomData);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Modify existing policy with the custom audit requirements
                    auditItem.CustomData = LabelCustomData;
                }
            }

            ct.Update(true);
        }
```

Comment: Is there any chance to programmatically create content type policies for SharePoint Online?